# How to set a bean name in Spring safely from a simpleClassName

Tags: java, spring

I need to use @DependsOn annotation and I'd like to get safely bean names. My current implementation is described below but I would prefer to have the constant CLASS_NAME set from ChildContextProvider.class.getSimpleName() or some similar implementation to achieve to find class usages easily and to be safe for a refactoring.

Bean with the constant:

```
@Component(value = WebhookManager.CLASS_NAME)
public class WebhookManager {

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = "WebhookManager";
    ...
}
```

Bean with @DependsOn annotation:

```
@RestController
@DependsOn({ChildContextProvider.CLASS_NAME, WebhookManager.CLASS_NAME})
public class PropertiesRESTController {
    ...
}
```

I am looking for a solution like this but this does not compile with message: CLASS_NAME must be constant:

```
@Component(value = WebhookManager.CLASS_NAME)
public class WebhookManager {

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = ChildContextProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a compile-time constants are allowed as an annotation value. In your case `CLASS_NAME` is not compile-time constant as long as result of `getSimpleName()` is calculated at the runtime.

You can read more about constant-time constants [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: Yes I understood this from message but I am asking for some solution. Maybe It does not exist.

Comment: The only solution I can see is to use your first example. You have to use a constant that is not calculated in runtime. Why using a String compile-time constant doesn't work for you?

Comment: It works but I was looking for something nicer to be safe for refactoring etc. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Cyva it is save for refactoring as long as your bean name is not changed if you rename the class. However, I wouldn't recommend you to rely on bean names anyway.